# How to map a Single User Model with multiple roles (student and teacher) to another model when relationship with the model varies based on user role?

Tags: django, django-models, user-roles

So, I have a `User` model in Django which can have three roles - teacher, student or both.

I have another Model, say `Course` which can have **only one teacher** but can have **multiple students** mapped to it.

How do I relate these models with another?

Answer (score 0):

Given the pseudo code:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='teaching')
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='studying')
```

If you have an User instance, you can check all courses it has as a student by calling `some_user.studying.all()`. Shall you want all given lectures by the same user, simply call `some_user.teaching.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Person(models.Model):           
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   class Meta:
       abstract = True

class Teacher(Person):
   salary = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Student(Person):
   roll_no = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Course(models.Model):
   std = models.ForeignKey(Student)
   mentor = models.OneToOneField(Teacher)
```